# What is the file to display a list of "post type" in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am looking for what file I can display my list post type. I've tried to display in `archive-posttype.php` but I haven't success.

```
<?php 
$newsArgs = array( 'post_type' => 'agenda', 'posts_per_page' => 4);                                    
$newsLoop = new WP_Query( $newsArgs );                                        
while ( $newsLoop->have_posts() ) : $newsLoop->the_post();
?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p><strong><?php the_time('d.m.Y') ?></strong></p>
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<p><?php //echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'categorias', 'Categorias: ', ' '); ?></p>
<p>Local: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'valor_meta', true); ?></p>       
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In  place of `$posttype` you must place the actual post type name, so if you are registered CPT with name `agenda` the file that you can display it is `archive-agenda.php`.
You can find more information [here](http://wphierarchy.com/) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

By the way, if you display your CPT (`agenda` for example) in (`archive-agenda.php`) and you use 'pretty permalinks' - your url for displaying agenda is `your-site-name.com/agenda/`, then no need to use custom query to display them, you can use default loop, i.e. in file `archive-agenda.php` you can display your custom posts as usual:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
   while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      the_title();
   endwhile;
endif;
```